# Zsys autosnapshots in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, zfs, snapshot

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS using the "advanced" ZFS installer.
It appears that the 20 minute snooze between Zsys autosnapshots in 20.04 LTS has been eliminated.  This means that each time a package is installed, there is a new snapshot.
This may be wise when a production machine is being modified, but is crazy when a machine is initially being set up.
When installing many packages on initial program load, as each apt-get -y install takes more than twice as long, and you get scores of snapshots.
I would love to have a command which would take a single snapshot, and then disable snapshots, and another which would turn snapshots back on for use in scripts.
Do such commands exist?  If not, could someone suggest script fragments which would accomplish this?